# how can I fix the problem in this command

Tags: python, django

django-admin startproject lecture3
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was includ
ed, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- django-admin startproject lecture3
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Suggestion [3,General]: The command django-admin was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\django-admin". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Comment: It literally tells you how to `If you trust this command, instead type: ".\django-admin"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell can't find the command in PATH, so if you are in `django-admin` directory type it with [.\](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7.2)

> To run a script that is in the current directory, specify the full path, or type a dot .\ to represent the current directory.

```
.\django-admin startproject lecture3
```